# How do I fork correctly in a perl module for znc?

Tags: perl, fork, irc

I'm currently writing an IRC bot. The scripts are loaded as perl modules in [ZNC](http://en.znc.in/wiki/ZNC) but the bot gets disconnected with an Input/Output error if I create a forked process. This is a working example script without fork, but this causes the bot to freeze until the script finishes doing its task.

```
package imdb;

use warnings;
use strict;


sub new
{
 my ($class) = @_;
 my $self = {};

 bless( $self, $class );
 return( $self );
}

sub OnChanMsg 
{
 my ($self, $nick, $channel,$text) = @_;

#unless (my $pid = fork()) {

 my $result = a_slow_process($text); 
 ZNC::PutIRC( "PRIVMSG $channel :$result" );
# exit;
#}

 return( ZNC::CONTINUE );

}

sub OnShutdown
{
 my ( $me ) = @_;
}

sub a_slow_process { 
my $input = shift; 
sleep 10; 
return "You said $input.";
 }

1;
```

The fork code that is causing the error is commented out. How do I fix this?

**Edited to add**: I was told that ZNC::PutIRC should not be put in the child process.

Comment: what is the error? does it happen the first attempt or afterwards? note that every time you call onchanmsg, you're creating a child process and dropping the original, so you are still calling PutIRC from a child process after the first time.  Are you sure you have thought out what is happening on both pathways of the fork?

Comment: The bot disconnects from IRC everytime saying "Input/output error". I don't know how to do the fork without putting ZNC::PutIRC in the child. I want it to send the message to IRC after it gets the result from a_slow_process(). The bot will be frozen until it returns ZNC::CONTINUE so I want that done as soon as the child is forked.

Answer (score 2):

A `fork()` call has effects on open file and socket handles, including:

> File descriptors (and sometimes locks on
>     those descriptors) are shared, while everything else is copied.
>
> ...
>
> Beginning with v5.6.0, Perl will attempt to flush all files
>   opened for output before forking the child process, but this
>   may not be supported on some platforms (see perlport).  To be
>   safe, you may need to set $| ($AUTOFLUSH in English) or call
>   the "autoflush()" method of "IO::Handle" on any open handles in
>   order to avoid duplicate output.

and in general it is not a good idea to set up a socket connection in one process and try to read/write on that connection in a child process.

A workaround might be to make a new ZNC connection in the child process (after `a_slow_process()` is done), write your private message, and then close the new connection.

Comment: Can you show me an example script with IO::Handle?

A new connection will lag a bit after it connects (especially if the bot is on a lot of channels), thus defeating the purpose of forking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not adverse to rewriting your module in c++, znc has a CExecSock which wraps popen2() and should do what you need.  You can look in the shell.cpp module for example usage.